# Trouble Deserializing JSON into Object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

Stack Overflow:

I am using JSON.NET and have done so successfully before, however I am now running into a nasty bit of JSON that I cannot seem to deserialize. Clearly the problem lays in how the class is constructed, and so I kindly ask for someone to help me plan a class that JSON.NET can successfully deserialize into.

Here is the structure of the JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "name":"",
        "cost":"",
        "cmc":"",
        "loyalty":"",
        "supertype":"",
        "type":"",
        "subtype":"",
        "power":"",
        "toughness":"",
        "hand":"",
        "life":"",
        "rule":"",
        "multi":"",
        "set":
        [   // Note: there could be an infinite number of sets
            {
                "setcode":"",
                "rarity":"",
                "number":"",
                "artist":"",
                "flavor":""
            },
            {   "setcode":"",
                "rarity":"",
                "number":"",
                "artist":"",
                "flavor":""
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you very much, Stack Overflow

Comment: Well, I know that it is the Set info that is giving me the trouble. I have tried a string array and a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to have a class with properties for all those names. When it comes to the array, it's really an array of objects so you need to create another class with same named properties. Something like:

```
public class MainObject
{
    public string name { get;set; }
    // rest of the names as properties
    public List<SetObject> @set { get;set; }

}

public class SetObject
{
    public string setcode { get;set; }
    // rest of your sets names as properties
}
```

Also, from your JSON it looks like it's an array already so you'll want to deserialize it as an array:

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainObject[]>(/* your json here */);
```

That will give you an array of your deserialized MainObject just like your JSON is an array.

Comment: @smoak - I take it that the '@set' is to avoid the C# keyword conflict.  I have never seen that syntax before.  Interesting.  I usually just add a JsonProperty attribute and specify Name.

Comment: @Frank - You're exactly right, in the OPs case his JSON has a name "set" and the easiest/quickest way to get it deserialized is to create a class with a property of that same name. Since the property name (set) is a C# keyword you need to use `@set` instead.